# SMS 60200 Invalid parameter error (400 bad request)

Tags: php, laravel, twilio

I'm trying to implement SMS authorization using PHP (Laravel).

I send all the data according to the documentation, but I get a parameter error.

In theory, everything should work correctly. This is the date that goes into the request:

```
array:2 [ // vendor/twilio/sdk/src/Twilio/Version.php:211
  "To" => "+380983435443"
  "Channel" => "sms"
]
```

Documentation https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/60200

Comment: Can you please link to the relevant documentation?

Comment: @CBroe added documentation link

Comment: I meant of the endpoint your are using, what parameters that _expects_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very vague question lot of things needed to be known to understand your issue...

from what I can see in the documentation you have received an error code of 60200 which is an invalid parameter...

according to documentation, the code should look like this

```
$twilio->messages
              ->create("+15558675310", // to
                       ["body" => "Hi there","from" => "+15017122661"]
              );
```

but here it looks like you have sent To and Channel as parameters..

Providing a snippet of your code where you have created the message would be more helpful.